# Can someone assist me with my KQL query to create an alert for login failures in Azure Sentinel?

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFXzZ.png)I am trying to build a alert for multiple login failures followed by success for a user on one host .

I got a query which is producing incorrect results . Currently its producing results of a user with multiple hosts

Can some one help me with the query ?

```
let timeRange = 6h;
let authenticationWindow = 1h;
let authenticationThreshold = 15;
SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(timeRange)
| where EventID == 4624 or EventID == 4625
| where IpAddress != "-" and isnotempty(Account) and AccountType == "User"
| extend Outcome = iff(EventID == 4624, "Success", "Failure")
| summarize OutcomeCount=count() by Account, IpAddress, Computer, Outcome,WorkstationName,TimeGenerated 
| project TimeGenerated, Account, IpAddress, Computer, Outcome, OutcomeCount, WorkstationName
| sort by Account asc, TimeGenerated asc
| serialize
| extend SessionStartedUtc = row_window_session(TimeGenerated, timeRange, authenticationWindow, Account != prev(Account) or prev(Outcome) == "Success")
| summarize FailureCountBeforeSuccess=sumif(OutcomeCount, Outcome == "Failure"), StartTime=min(TimeGenerated), EndTime=max(TimeGenerated), makelist(Outcome), Computer=makeset(Computer), IpAddress=makeset(IpAddress),WorkstationName=makeset(WorkstationName) by SessionStartedUtc, Account
| where array_index_of(list_Outcome, "Success") != 0
| where array_index_of(list_Outcome, "Success") == array_length(list_Outcome) - 1
| project-away SessionStartedUtc, list_Outcome
| where FailureCountBeforeSuccess >= authenticationThreshold
```

SAMPLE LOG:

[Sample log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anp0K.png)

Comment: Please provide your current querry and a data sample.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/14853083)

Comment: @FlorianVuillemot : i have pasted the query and attached image for sample logs .Current issue with query is it provides login failures of a user from one machine and login success from another machine which is not what i am looking for . i am looking for is let say if there is 16 events  for a user then 15 are failures and last one is a success on the same host for the same user

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways I haven't looked at this that performs sequence matching. but from a simplicity point of view, I've made a query that generates an array which you can then pattern match against it.

```
let timeRange = 6h;
let authenticationWindow = 1h;
let authenticationThreshold = 15;
let authenticationPattern = extract(@"^\[(.*)\]$",1,tostring(array_concat(repeat(0, authenticationThreshold),dynamic([1])))); // This will generate a pattern of sequential 0, followed by 1. This represents failed logins followed by a success
SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(timeRange)
| where EventID in (4624,4625)
| where AccountType == "User"
| extend Account = tolower(Account)
| extend Outcome = case(EventID == 4624, 1, 0) // if the login is successfull, set the value to 1, else 0
| order by TimeGenerated
| summarize OutcomeList = tostring(make_list(Outcome)) by Account, Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, authenticationWindow)
| where OutcomeList contains authenticationPattern
| extend EndTime = TimeGenerated + authenticationWindow - 1tick
| project StartTime = TimeGenerated, EndTime, Account, Computer, OutcomeList
```

kind regards

Alistair